# Coming up with logic to be able to add a time interval if the same date exists for the same clip#

Tags: sql, date, datetime, logic, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to separate out a clip if it has the same date. For example, since "Clip Number" 1 and 2 has the same date so I am trying to make the date different by adding a 6 hour interval. I would like to add a new field that is similar to the column "New Date"

| Date | Clip_Number | New Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/2/2021 | 1 | 1/2/2021 0:00 |
| 1/2/2021 | 1 | 1/2/2021 0:00 |
| 1/2/2021 | 2 | 1/2/2021 6:00 |
| 1/2/2021 | 2 | 1/2/2021 6:00 |
| 1/3/2021 | 3 | 1/3/2021 0:00 |
| 1/3/2021 | 3 | 1/3/2021 0:00 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gordon solution works, but only if "there are only two values with the same date".

This solution works even in that case:

```sql
with data as (
select 1 clip, '2020-10-03' d
union all select 1, '2020-10-03'
union all select 1, '2020-10-03'
union all select 2, '2020-10-03'
union all select 2, '2020-10-03'
union all select 3, '2020-10-03'
union all select 3, '2020-10-04'
union all select 3, '2020-10-04'
)

select *
  , timestampadd('hour'
      , 6*(-1+dense_rank() over(partition by d order by clip))
      , d
    ) new_date
from data
```

[image]

Comment: this is helpful. if I am understanding correctly, this would essentially add an additional 6 hours to every clip where the date is the same?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are only two values with the same date, you could use:

```
select t.*,
       (case when clip_number <> min(clip_number) over (partition by date)
             then date + interval '6 hour'
             else date
        end)
from t;
```

Comment: thank you. This is helpful. Now, there are only two values so this works but you never know if it will change in the future.

Comment: @analytica . . . This answers the question that you asked here.